# Else without if - android studio/java

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm writing a code for a calculator. I'm having an error **"else without if"** at the **last "else" in the code**. If you could help me figure out what it is I would be grateful :)

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String string = "";
String string1 = "";

public void onClick1(View v) {

    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Button button = (Button) v;

    string = (String) button.getText().toString();

    if (!string.contains("+") && !string.contains("-") && !string.contains("*") && !string.contains("/")) {

        string1 = string1 + string;

        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
            arrayList.remove((arrayList.size() - 1));
        }

        arrayList.add(string1);
    } else {
        arrayList.add(string);
        arrayList.add(string);
        string1 = "";
    }

    //textView2.setText(textView2.getText().toString()+string);

    textView2.setText(arrayList.toString());
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    int calc = 0;
    int c = arrayList.size();

    while (c != 1) {

        if (c > 3) {

            if (arrayList.get(3).contains("*") || arrayList.get(3).contains("/")) {

                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("*")) {
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));
                }
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("/")) {
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2)) / Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));
                }

                arrayList.remove(2);
                arrayList.remove(2);
                arrayList.remove(2);
                arrayList.add(2, Integer.toString(calc));
                c = arrayList.size();
            } else {
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+"))
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-"))
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) - Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
        }
        if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*"))
            calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));

        {
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/"))
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) / Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));

            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(calc));
            c = arrayList.size();

            else {
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                }
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                }
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*")) {
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                }
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/")) {
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                }

                arrayList.remove(0);
                arrayList.remove(0);
                arrayList.remove(0);
                arrayList.remove(0);
                arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(calc));
                c = arrayList.size();
            }
        }
        textView1.setText(Integer.toString(calc));
    }
}

public void clear(View v) {
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    string1 = "";
    string = "";
    textView1.setText("0");
    textView2.setText("");
    arrayList.clear();
}
```

Comment: i think once again you need to check your code, there is some issues

Comment: See the curly brackets, you missed many of them in the onClick method. ctrl+f

Comment: Your IDE should help you with this, shouldn't it?

Comment: In android studio, sometimes they take valid 'else' as an error( else without if).so just make 'if and else first', then replace everythin you have under 'error else',

Answer (score 1):

You can check this code of `onClick()` method. You better format your code. I have added comments to point out issues.

```
...
if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*"))
    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));

{ // <----------------------------this is redundant 
    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/"))
        calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) / Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));

    arrayList.remove(0); // this code is not in above if block.
    arrayList.remove(0);
    arrayList.remove(0);
    arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(calc));
    c = arrayList.size();

    else { // <----------------------------this else is without if
        ...
```

**Note:** I haven't checked your logic.

---

Refer: [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html), it states that

> The opening and closing braces are optional, provided that the "then" clause contains only one statement

Answer (score 0):

Error in line 60. Here else block is defined without its if block. Also see line number. Also see line 47. Block start '{' without any if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I have just removed error by formatting your code and adding curly braces at two places :

Please check if both braces at proper position for your logic:
Here both are highlighted :

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String string = "";
String string1 = "";

public void onClick1(View v) {

    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Button button = (Button) v;

    string = (String) button.getText().toString();

    if (!string.contains("+") && !string.contains("-") && !string.contains("*") && !string.contains("/")) {

        string1 = string1 + string;

        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {

            arrayList.remove((arrayList.size() - 1));


        }

        arrayList.add(string1);
    } else {
        arrayList.add(string);
        arrayList.add(string);
        string1 = "";

    }

    //textView2.setText(textView2.getText().toString()+string);

    textView2.setText(arrayList.toString());
}


public void onClick(View v) {

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    int calc = 0;
    int c = arrayList.size();


    while (c != 1) {

        if (c > 3) {

            if (arrayList.get(3).contains("*") || arrayList.get(3).contains("/")) {

                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("*")) {
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));
                }
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("/")) {
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2)) / Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));
                }

                arrayList.remove(2);
                arrayList.remove(2);
                arrayList.remove(2);
                arrayList.add(2, Integer.toString(calc));
                c = arrayList.size();
            } else

            {
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+"))
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-"))
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) - Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
        }
        if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*")) {// added here
            calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));

            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/"))
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) / Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));

            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(calc));
            c = arrayList.size();

        // added below before else word
        } else {

            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*")) {
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/")) {
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }

            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(calc));
            c = arrayList.size();


        }
    }


    textView1.setText(Integer.toString(calc));

}



public void clear(View v) {

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    string1 = "";
    string = "";
    textView1.setText("0");
    textView2.setText("");
    arrayList.clear();


} //removed from here
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Properly indented, your code looks like this:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String string = "";
String string1 = "";

public void onClick1(View v) {

    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Button button = (Button) v;

    string = (String) button.getText().toString();

    if (!string.contains("+") && !string.contains("-") && !string.contains("*") && !string.contains("/")) {

        string1 = string1 + string;

        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {

            arrayList.remove((arrayList.size() - 1));


        }

        arrayList.add(string1);
    } else {
        arrayList.add(string);
        arrayList.add(string);
        string1 = "";

    }

    //textView2.setText(textView2.getText().toString()+string);

    textView2.setText(arrayList.toString());
}


public void onClick(View v) {

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    int calc = 0;
    int c = arrayList.size();


    while (c != 1) {

        if (c > 3) {

            if (arrayList.get(3).contains("*") || arrayList.get(3).contains("/")) {

                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("*")) {
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));
                }
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("/")) {
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2)) / Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));
                }

                arrayList.remove(2);
                arrayList.remove(2);
                arrayList.remove(2);
                arrayList.add(2, Integer.toString(calc));
                c = arrayList.size();
            } else

            {
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+"))
                    calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-"))
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) - Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
        }
        if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*"))
            calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
        {
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/"))
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) / Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));

            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(calc));
            c = arrayList.size();


            else{

            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*")) {
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/")) {
                calc = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
            }

            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.remove(0);
            arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(calc));
            c = arrayList.size();


        }
        }


        textView1.setText(Integer.toString(calc));

    }

}


public void clear(View v) {

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    string1 = "";
    string = "";
    textView1.setText("0");
    textView2.setText("");
    arrayList.clear();


}
```

It should now be reasonably easy to see that you're missing curly brackets in certain places.

Something of note: sometimes you're doing this:

```
if(something)
    dosomething();
```

Whilst this is technically fine, it can sneak errors into your code (say if you add something else later). My advice is to err on the side of caution and always use brackets - so it becomes more like this:

```
if(something){
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Ok so now i fixed the code by adding the curly brackets, thanks to everyone. And now I start my emulator, start typing some numbers, the app closes when i press the equals button, when I want an answer to a calculation. Any ideas? "Unfortunetaly, my calculator has stopped working"

Comment: Check your LogCat entry, if you can't solve it then post a new quetion